# Compress and Minify WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd in ASP.NET 4 WebForms

Tags: asp.net, performance, webforms, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I have been trying for a week now to reduce the number of requests on our web application but I can't seem to combine the `.axd` files. I got a suggestion from somewhere which worked locally (development box) but doesn't work on our test and production environment as they are both on `HTTPS`. The developer didn't comment on that and the component he wrote was last updated in 2011. (I will find the link and update this post).

I tried using the `CompositeScript` in `ScriptManager` and again it doesn't work on Test/Production environments.

I used SquishIt to resolve the other files. (see attachment)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To force it work on your environment, set [`ScriptMode="Release"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344940(v=vs.110).aspx) eg as:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScrMang" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"  >
    <CompositeScript>
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference name="Common.Common.js" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </Scripts>
    </CompositeScript>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

### Some more notes

To find what scripts to add inside `CompositeScript` you can use the code from here : http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/13356 and get more help how to use it from this page : https://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/aspnet-ajax-performance/

Comment: Although this didn't minify or compress the `WebResource.axd`, it at least minified the `ScriptResource.axd`. There were cases where I had more than one `ScriptResource.axd` and it combined them as well. Thanks @Aristos for your help.

Comment: @SollyM Yes you are correct, is not minified. To minified I use this https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584  and I pass the code from it... but if you just gZip its also ok from the manner of download speed...

Comment: I had to unmark it as an answer. This 'CompositeScript' prevents postbacks. I have been trying to resolve postbacks while it was intact but failed. once I remove it my forms post fine.

Comment: @SollyM I use this kind of script years now with out any problem.  I really do not know whats your issue is with the prevent post back that you say. Hope to find it.

Comment: @SollyM Check what is the error message, also check what kind of script reference you need to add. Here I have add some for demonstration, you need to find all your script using the above links on the answer. Probably you forget to add some scripts.

Comment: I think the main problem is that my test/production servers run on HTTPS. Locally (development) I don't have HTTPS and therefore works fine. However when I put it on the Test server/production server it fails. HTTPS is the only thing I can think of as I set up the server myself and replicated my development box.

Comment: @SollyM No its not that, I have the same https/http on my pages

Comment: I have finally accepted this as an answer even though on my side is still doesn't work. You claim to have the solution working for your pages and therefore I cannot deny others the opportunity of using your solution if they encounter the same problem.

Comment: @SollyM There is also this link on a block with full tutorial https://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/aspnet-ajax-performance/   the only that is not done here automatically is the minification.

Comment: Could you please look at this and help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198461/combining-multiple-calls-to-scriptresource-axd

Comment: @bjan Yes of cource I will look at it, now I am living for 3-4 hours, later I will see it again.